# Chart.js how set equal step size depending on actual data (xaxis)?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to achiev that the setp size of the xaxis depends on the actual value from the label. Here an example of excel how I expect my chart.js line chart should look the step on the x-axis is "2":
[image: Chart from excel]

But my chart.js always distributes the labels equally on the xaxis:
[image: Chart.js example]

My xaxis settings:

```
xAxes: [{
    display: true,
    scaleLabel: {
      display: true,
      labelString: 'Test'  
    },
    ticks:
    {
    min: 1,
    max:17,
    stepSize: 5,
    },
    distribution: 'linear',

  }],
```

Here a link to my chart.js example: https://jsfiddle.net/h97remq3/1/

I tried the whole afternoon different x-axis settings but never get my desired result like in excel. I think the solution should be an easy setting, but I didn't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `line` chart, use a 'scatter' chart. Then omit `data.labels` and define the `data` in [point format](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#data-structure) as follows.

```
data: [
  { x: 1, y: 10 },
  { x: 2, y: 2 },
  { x: 3, y: 5 },
  { x: 5, y: 22 },
  { x: 10, y: 17 },
  { x: 15, y: 11 },
  { x: 17, y: 3 }
],
```

Please have a look at your amended [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kfL68car/1/).